# Searching for hashtags using Apache Pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I am trying to determine the top 10 hashtags in a text file containing tweets in the following format:

```
USER_79321756   2010-03-05T04:48:05 ÜT: 47.528139,-122.197916   47.528139   -122.197916 Just talkin too for real. Ha.
USER_79321756   2010-03-05T20:25:56 ÜT: 47.528139,-122.197916   47.528139   -122.197916 RT @USER_620cd4b9: @USER_79321756 hey now! Leave me, and my big eyes alone LOL&gt;&gt;lol NO! :*
USER_4659ef22   2010-03-06T05:50:54 ÜT: 40.816206,-73.894429    40.816206   -73.894429  But where's @USER_55e0f4ff?? Hmmm shawty where u at?
USER_064b120e   2010-03-03T18:56:49 ÜT: 34.223957,-118.600448   34.223957   -118.600448 @USER_4a4d09c2 the ludacris one . have you heard it , he got off on that one .
```

I came up with the following snippet to do so.

**CODE:**

```
a = load '/user/lab/pig/full_text_small.txt' AS (id:chararray, ts:chararray, location:chararray, lat:float, lon:float, tweet:chararray);
b = foreach a generate tweet, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(LOWER(tweet))) as tokens;
c = filter b by STARTSWITH(tokens,'#');
d = group c by tokens;
e = foreach d generate group as tokens, COUNT(c) as cnt;
f = order e by cnt desc;
g = limit f 10;
dump g;
```

This gives the result shown below.

**RESULT:**

```
  (#ff, 55)
  (#inhighschool, 25)
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  (#random, 9)
  (#mewithoutyouislike, 7)
```

I have included an image of the output as well.

[Output showing top 10 hashtags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzZvi.jpg)

However, if I open the text file (full_text_small.txt) containing the tweets in a word editor and search for the hashtag "#ff' (case-insensitive), I get a total count of 61 and not 55. Similarly, the counts for all the other hashtags in the output are different from those obtained using Pig.

Further, when I use a different matching technique, namely the one shown below, I get a slightly different result.

**CODE:**

```
a = load '/user/lab/pig/full_text_small.txt' AS (id:chararray, ts:chararray, location:chararray, lat:float, lon:float, tweet:chararray);
b = foreach a generate tweet, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(LOWER(tweet))) as tokens;
c = filter b by tokens MATCHES '#\\s*(\\w+)';
d = group c by tokens;
e = foreach d generate group as tokens, COUNT(c) as cnt;
f = order e by cnt desc;
g = limit f 10;
dump g;
```

**RESULT:**

```
  (#ff, 55)
  (#inhighschool, 25)
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  (#random, 9)
  (#realgrandmas, 7)
```

Image of the output of the second code snippet:

[Second output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I23jt.jpg)

All the hashtags in the outputs for the two code snippets are the same except for the last ones.

My questions are the following:

1. Why am I getting different results for the two snippets in terms of 
   the last hashtag?
2. Why do the results obtained using these snippets
   not match those obtained using the search function in a text
   editor?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my theories:

1. The last hashtag changing doesn't have anything to do with the two snippets you mentioned. Since both the hashtags have same counts, it is not deterministic as to which will get higher preference during the `SORT` and subsequent `LIMIT`.
2. Since you are using `TOKENIZE` followed by a `STARTSWITH`, you are expecting the hashtags to be preceded by a space. While searching in you text editor maybe your search is including the "#ff" hashtags which are not preceded by spaces as well.